# declarative_authorization problem with creating new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used declarative_authorization for my app and had problem with creating new user.

my User model code:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ROLE_TYPES = ["admin", "user", "guest"]    
    validates_inclusion_of :roles, :in => ROLE_TYPES

    def role_symbols
       @role_symbols ||= (roles || []).map{|r| r.to_sym} 
    end
```

my view code:

```
   <% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      ...
      <p>
         <%= f.label :roles %><br />
         <%= f.select :roles, User::ROLE_TYPES, :prompt => "Select a role" %>
      </p>
      <%= f.submit 'Add User' %>
   <% end %>
```

every time i tried to create a new user and select the role from the drop-down list, the view complaint:

```
Roles is not included in the list
```

from the output of the script/server, i can see the roles was actually set:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"kc", "password_confirmation"=>"kc", "roles"=>"guest", "password"=>"kc", "email"=>"kc@one.com"}
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong? why the validation wont' pass?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you've got `attr_accessible` attributes on the user to prevent mass assignment of certain attributes and that `:roles` isn't in there? You would get a warning about this in your logs though. The default User class generated by restful_authentication does include the attr_accessible call so it may be there without you having added it if you are using that authentication plugin too.

Is there definitely a roles attribute of the right type for users? It looks like you're expecting roles to be a single string from your form but in the code from declarative_authorization you've got `(roles || []).map` which suggests that that part of the code at least is expecting an array of roles.